# Ошибка <Response [400]> при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, парсер

Пытаюсь сделать запрос к сайту: `https://www.mvideo.ru/bff/products?productIds=50126638,50160742,50148100,50131384,50143248,50046709,50126637,50047745,50048049,50149763,50048263,50142809,50049396,50143232,50041095,50049029,50141257,50129927,50141256,50144286,50048261,50149764,50129501,50141255` для получения списка товаров по id в JSON формате. И при таком запросе трубуется подставлять куки, по этому нагуглив в закаулках я понял что нужно подключаться через session(), так куки будут подставляться автоматически. Но по итогу я получаю в консоль `<Response [400]>`
А если делать просто Get запрос, получится такая ошибка:

```
{"errors":["MVID_CITY_ID,MVID_REGION_ID,MVID_REGION_SHOP,bIPs,JSESSIONID,MVID_TIMEZONE_OFFSET,MVID_GUEST_ID cookie(s) should be passed in the request header"],"traceId":"928eb5b8-c659-49f7-a68d-39b70f0cbb47","errorData":null,"statusCode":400,"source":"BFF","externalUrl":null}
```

Сам код с Session:

```
import ssl
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bss



url = 'https://www.mvideo.ru/bff/products?productIds=50126638,50160742,50148100,50131384,50143248,50046709,50126637,50047745,50048049,50149763,50048263,50142809,50049396,50143232,50041095,50049029,50141257,50129927,50141256,50144286,50048261,50149764,50129501,50141255'


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}


session = requests.Session()
reg = session.get(url,headers=headers)
print(reg)
```

Тут пытался подставить куки вручную:

```
import ssl
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bss



url = 'https://www.mvideo.ru/bff/products?productIds=50126638,50160742,50148100,50131384,50143248,50046709,50126637,50047745,50048049,50149763,50048263,50142809,50049396,50143232,50041095,50049029,50141257,50129927,50141256,50144286,50048261,50149764,50129501,50141255'
cookie = {'MVID_CITY_ID': 'CityCZ_975', 'MVID_REGION_ID': '1', 'MVID_REGION_SHOP': 'S002', 'bIPs': '-957002303', 'JSESSIONID': 'Z2gbhgfSwHC4KrtyWq7G2dpMLJGQ1W2h4pyxXGQnCQ6Q16vhYV0j', 'MVID_TIMEZONE_OFFSET': '3', 'MVID_GUEST_ID': '17992078087'}


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}
def get_html(url,params=None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params,cookies=cookie)

    return r

def parse():
    html = get_html(url)
    return str(html.text)

print(parse())

with open("file.html", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    f.write(parse())
```

Comment: Решил проблему, бро?
Опиши как плиз

Comment: @user467117 Брал куки от сайта mvideo, сохранял в переменную и передавал их при запросе в xhr

Answer (score 0):

используй https://curlconverter.com/# , он поможет тебе правильные заголовки и куки установить, при запросе через браузер зайти в network и на запросе к странице ПКМ -> COPY ->COPY ALL as cURL и то что скопировал вставляй на сайт и потом просто копируй себе